# Copy activity fails if optional XML tag does not exist

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am parsing a large xml file into multiple tables using multiple Copy Data activities.

One such table uses an optional XML tag that is also the Collection reference, when this tag is not included in the xml the pipeline logging shows the result that it failed due to not finding this xml tag.

`Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorTypeInSchemaTableNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to get the type from schema table. This could be caused by missing Sql Server System CLR Types.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Type'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'`

I have set fault tolerance on this activity to skip incompatible rows but this has no effect.

I think I could use a lookup to check if the tag exists at runtime but I want to know if there is a more ideal solution to this issue.

Comment: I ran into this exact problem today. Did you find an solution to your problem?

Comment: We ended up creating a lookup for that tag and use an if / else step. Not an elegant solution